# How to hide a rectangle where horizontal and vertical scroll bars converge?

Tags: css

I have changed overflow CSS but my app design is dark, so I can see white rectangular where both scroll bars converge. How to hide it?

[image: rectangular]

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px grey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #edde5d;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #f09819;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this CSS as per your convenience, it would work fine :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0); // transparent or any other color you want
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. :)